# call parent method from child constructor

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
class Parent{
    constructor(){
        ...
    }

    methodA(){
        ...
    }
}

class Child extends Parent{
    constructor(){
        super()
        ...
        super.methodA() // <=== ok ???
        this.methodA()  // <=== ok ???
    }
}
```

Suggest workaround if not legal?

I think the question is self-evident but this site wants more text, so here it is.

Comment: Gihan: thanks. That was an oops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as per your given code both works. But `super.methodA()` and `this.methodA()` are different. If you override the `methodA` from the child class you can see the difference.

```
class Child extends Parent{
    constructor(){
        super()
        ...
        super.methodA() // this calls the Parent class's methodA
        this.methodA()  // this will call the Child class's methodA
    }

    methodA() {

    }
}
```

Here's a demo from the JS bin 
https://jsbin.com/zisamideyu/edit?js,console

Comment: Mmmm. I thought it would work, but I get "MethodA is not a function" whatever I try. I was thinking maybe something to do with calling from inside constructor

Comment: Please check the demo form the jsbin

Comment: the jsbin is very convincing and answers the question so I'll tick it. I'll do more testing as this is in a web component definition. Maybe they are different

Answer (score 0):

```
if child has methodA
    use super.methodA()
else
    use this.methodA()
```

Comment: Per the question, the child does NOT have a methodA. The question is if it legal to make the call from the child constructor, in either of these ways, or in some other.

Comment: of course is legal, you can restrict access by using private fields. now es6 has [private fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields#Private_fields) like #data

Comment: I'm not sure what private fields have to do with this question, but in any case to say "es6 has private fields" is misleading as they are still experimental and not widely supported.